# How to invoke a function in an if statement that will write to a database when the weight changes

Tags: java, database, if-statement

I am attempting to invoke a function(as seen in the pseudo code below) that will count 50 or so readings of a carton of 6 eggs as it calibrates the weight on my USB DYMO M5 scale, of the carton and once one egg is removed it will write one egg to a shopping database table and remove one egg from the 6 in a fridge database. I was wondering what would be the most efficient way of going about this would be? Any feedback would be appreciated.

int count = 0;
        int oldweight=0;

```
    //oldweight = weight;
    if (oldweight == weight) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        System.out.println("Weight Changes");
        /* write DB


        //if (weight < oldweight){
        //then something was taken off
         * 
         * remove equivalent amount of eggs from db.fridge.

        //if(db.frdige == 0 eggs){
            //order eggs
        }

        if(weight > oldweight){
            somebody put eggs in the fridge. 
        }
        *
        *
        *


    }*/
        oldweight=weight;
    }

    if (weight != oldweight) {
        while (count <= 5000) {
            count++;
        }
        while (count < 5)
            weight = count++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step: When working with a database in general in java,  you write a class to represent the table in the database This is known as a 'bean'. You could categorize the foodlist and fridge list as general items.

```
package scrap;

public class FoodList {

private String Vegetable;
private String meat;
private String liquid;
private String other;

public FoodList() {
    //default constructor
}

public String getVegetable() {
    return Vegetable;
}
public void setVegetable(String vegetable) {
    Vegetable = vegetable;
}
public String getMeat() {
    return meat;
}
public void setMeat(String meat) {
    this.meat = meat;
}
public String getLiquid() {
    return liquid;
}
public void setLiquid(String liquid) {
    this.liquid = liquid;
}
public String getOther() {
    return other;
}
public void setOther(String other) {
    this.other = other;
}
```

}

Fridge class like this:

```
package scrap;

public class FridgeContents {
private String Vegetable;
private String meat;
private String liquid;
private String other;

public FridgeContents() {
    //default constructor
}

public String getVegetable() {
    return Vegetable;
}
public void setVegetable(String vegetable) {
    Vegetable = vegetable;
}
public String getMeat() {
    return meat;
}
public void setMeat(String meat) {
    this.meat = meat;
}
public String getLiquid() {
    return liquid;
}
public void setLiquid(String liquid) {
    this.liquid = liquid;
}
public String getOther() {
    return other;
}
public void setOther(String other) {
    this.other = other;
}
```

}
Then you will need a class that will create a connection to the database program you work with, and a 'rowmapper' class which is a class that writes the contents of the database returns to the bean.
   Without writing all of this out, suffice it to say that database tables are matched to Java beans, and there are many different styles and methods of writing to the beans depending on the framework and project you are using.